# Is atomic.LoadUint32 necessary?

Tags: go, atomic

Go's atomic package provides function `func LoadUint32(addr *uint32) (val uint32)`. I looked into the assembly implementation:

```
TEXT ·LoadUint32(SB),NOSPLIT,$0-12
MOVQ    addr+0(FP), AX
MOVL    0(AX), AX
MOVL    AX, val+8(FP)
RET
```

which basically load the value from the memory address and return it.
I'm wondering if we have a uint32 pointer(addr) `x`, what is the difference between calling `atomic.LoadUint32(x)` and directly access it using `*x`?

Comment: The first is guaranteed to be atomic, the second not.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> which basically load the value from the memory address and return it.

That is the case in your context, but might differ on a different machine architecture where **[atomicity](http://www.1024cores.net/home/lock-free-algorithms/so-what-is-a-memory-model-and-how-to-cook-it)** is to be implemented, as [discussed here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/CJwyejWMTBQ).
As mentioned in [go issue 8739](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/8739#issuecomment-270486766)

> We intrinsify both `sync/atomic` and `runtime/internal/atomic` for a bunch of architectures.
> The APIs are not unified (e.g. [`LoadUint32`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/atomic/#LoadUint32) in [`sync/atomic`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/atomic/) is [`Load`](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/internal/atomic/#Load) in [`runtime/internal/atomic`](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/internal/atomic/)).

(* "intrinsify" as in [issue 4947](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/4947))

As mentioned in my first link:

> Regarding loads and stores.
>
> Memory model along with instruction set specifies whether plain loads and stores are atomic or not. Typical guarantee for all modern commodity hardware is that aligned word-sized loads and stores are atomic. For example, on x86 architecture (IA-32 and Intel 64) 1-, 2-, 4-, 8- and 16-byte aligned loads and stores are all atomic (that is, plain `MOV` instruction, `MOVQ` and `MOVDQA` are atomic).